# Project Honeypot httpbl python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

im trying to check the reputation of a IP address using [project honeypot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/index.php) python API. But when i try the [example code](https://github.com/gmr/httpbl) on a jupyter notebook:

```
import httpbl
ip_address = '188.37.87.45'
key = '*****'

bl = httpbl.HttpBL(key)
response = bl.query(ip_address)

print "IP Address: %s" % ip_address
print "Threat Score: %i" % response['threat_score']
print "Days since last activity: %i" % response['days_since_last_activity']
print "Visitor type: %s" % ', '.join([httpbl.DESCRIPTIONS[type_] \
                                      for type_ in response['type']])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2225af148800> in <module>()
----> 1 from httpbl import HttpBL
      2 ip_address = '188.37.87.45'
      3 key = '*****'
      4 
      5 bl = httpbl.HttpBL(key)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httpbl/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 __version__ = 0, 0, 3
      6 
----> 7 from httpbl import HttpBL
      8 
      9 # Response constants

ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpBL'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I think the problem is i'm using python 3.

Comment: It's a Python 3 issue. Will release 0.4 shortly.